# Can't run VMware Workstation player on Ubuntu 17.04 due to gcc-7.1 problem

Tags: vmware, gcc

I am trying to run **VMware-Player-12.5.7-5813279.x86_64** on Ubuntu 17.04.

I installed it without problems but when I run it I get a message that gcc 7.1.0 is not found

[image: error message]

running

```
gcc --version
```

gives me 6.3.0

I tried following the guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011798/how-can-i-update-my-gcc-6-3-0-to-gcc-7-1-0-in-ubuntu-17-04) to install gcc-7 on Ubuntu 17.04. Then I tried following [this guide](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/) in order to switch to an alternative compiler, but after doing it and typing

```
gcc --version
```

I get that I have gcc 7.0.1

Consequently, I still can't run VMware-Player.

I am running Kernel 4.12.8

I also tried the [guide here](https://www.techandme.se/how-to-install-vmware-workstation-12-on-linux-4-10-kernel/), after doing all the previous steps, with and without reinstalling anything, whereby I changed (4,10,0) in the guide to (4,12,0), to no avail.

Can somebody help?

**UPDATE:** I ran

```
sudo update-alternatives --list gcc
```

and the output is

```
/usr/bin/gcc-6
/usr/bin/gcc-7
```

also

```
sudo update-alternatives --display gcc | column -t
```

giving

```
gcc             -          manual          mode
link            best       version         is            /usr/bin/gcc-7
link            currently  points          to            /usr/bin/gcc-7
link            gcc        is              /usr/bin/gcc
slave           g++        is              /usr/bin/g++
/usr/bin/gcc-6  -          priority        60
slave           g++:       /usr/bin/g++-6
/usr/bin/gcc-7  -          priority        60
slave           g++:       /usr/bin/g++-7
```

Comment: Please run `sudo update-alternatives --list gcc` and lets see the output.

Comment: @George Added the required information as an edit to the post

Comment: Please also run this `sudo update-alternatives --display gcc | column -t` and add the output.

Comment: @George Done with that

Comment: All seems good from what I see, so don't know why VMWare isn't installing

Comment: Please restart your system and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @George It is installing, but it doesn't allow me to start it. I put a picture of the message I am getting. Also put in my Kernel version and how I tried implementing the guide in the last link I have provided, based on my Kernel version

Comment: @George I tried restarting, doesn't help.

Comment: Did you use the `ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1` repo or the other?

Comment: @George `ppa:jonathonf/gcc-7.1` doesn't work for me, because I am on 17.04, so I used the other one

Comment: @ThunderBiggi did you give VMware the `/usr/bin/gcc-7` path for its installer?  When you use `update-alternatives` it sets `gcc` to whatever the 'default' is, but sometimes it's looking for a specific compiler binary name/path rather than the generic `gcc`.

Comment: @ThomasWard I gave VMware the `\usr\bin\gcc-7` path, is that wrong?. It is now asking for 7.2.0 by the way. I am still with 7.0.1 as given by `gcc --version`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get past the gcc problem (which is now at 7.2.0). I used the steps [here](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2016/10/07/building-gcc-ubuntu-linux/), modifying them for gcc-7.2.0. (**This is for 64bits system**)

So, download the GCC 7 source and prerequisites from [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html)

```
cd ~
wget http://gcc.parentingamerica.com/releases/gcc-7.2.0/gcc-7.2.0.tar.xz
tar xf gcc-7.2.0.tar.xz
cd gcc-7.2.0
contrib/download_prerequisites
```

We will install the compiler in `/usr/local/gcc-7.2`, as not to mess with the default compiler, **as this might break your system**.

```
cd ~
mkdir build && cd build
../gcc-7.2.0/configure -v --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr/local/gcc-7.2 --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-multilib --program-suffix=-7.2
```

Then we build the thing with

```
make -j 8
```

where we have specified that we want 8 threads to work on the job at the same time. The reason for this is that I have 4 cores that are hyperthreaded (they can each process 2 threads at the same time). Adjust this according to your setup. *This step takes a lot of time* - took me around 30 minutes on a decent laptop. Once the above is done, install the compiler

```
sudo make install
```

Now we jsut have to tell our system to use this compiler. I didn't do what is advised in the guide that I have linked at the top, instead I followed [this](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2011-12-24_GCCv47/) in order to set up an alternative compiler by doing

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/local/gcc-7.2.0/bin/gcc-7.2 50 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/local/gcc-7.2.0/bin/g++-7.2
```

And then selecting the alternative compiler, using

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

Comment: Has anyone tried this? ..I also need to install gcc-7.2 on my Ubuntu 14.04 in order to run VM Workstation Player.

Comment: I tried it and it works

Comment: Worked for me. Minor correction to the second from last command, for those that are copy and pasting - remove the minor version number:
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/local/gcc-7.2/bin/gcc-7.2 50 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/local/gcc-7.2/bin/g++-7.2

Answer (score 1):

This process (including dmcquiggin's change in the comments) worked for me for:

Version: VMWare Workstation 14 Pro (14.1.1 build-7528167) 
OS: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-041500-generic

With one caveat:
I had to edit the download_prerequisites script to point it to another mirror as ftp://gcc.gnu.org/pub/gcc/infrastructure/ was down.

I used the mirror:
http://gcc.skazkaforyou.com/infrastructure/
instead.

This is one of the official GCC mirrors.